# How to extract only year(YYYY) from a CSV column with data like YYYY-YY

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-visualization, bokeh

I am new to Python/Bokeh/Pandas.

I am able to plot line graph in pandas/bokeh using parse_date options.

However I have come across a dataset(.csv) where the column is like below
[image]

My code is as below which gives a blank graph if the column 'Year/Ports' is in YYYY-YY form like from 1952-53, 1953-54, 1954-55 etc.

Do I have to extract only the YYYY and plot because that works but I am sure that is not how the data is to be visualized.

If I extract only the YYYY using CSV or Notepad++ tools then there is no issue as the dates are read perfectly and I get a good meaningful line graph

```
#Total Cargo Handled at Mormugao Port from 1950-51 to 2019-20

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show
from bokeh.io import output_file

#read the CSV file shared by GOI

df = pd.read_csv("Cargo_Data_full.csv",parse_dates=["Year/Ports"])

# selecting rows based on condition

output_file("Cargo tracker.html")


f = figure(height=200,sizing_mode = 'scale_width',x_axis_type = 'datetime')

f.title.text = "Cargo Tracker"
f.xaxis.axis_label="Year/Ports"
f.yaxis.axis_label="Cargo handled"

f.line(df['Year/Ports'],df['OTHERS'])

show(f)
```

Comment: I have no way of testing this but you could try: f.line([y[:4] for y in df['Year/Ports']],df['OTHERS'])

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `parse_dates` in this case, since the format is not a valid datetime. You can use `pandas` string slicing to only keep the YYYY part.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year/Ports':['1952-53', '1953-54', '1954-55'], 'val':[1,2,3]})

df['Year/Ports'] = df['Year/Ports'].str[:4]

print(df)

  Year/Ports  val
0       1952    1
1       1953    2
2       1954    3
```

From there you can turn it into a `datetime` if that makes sense for you.

```
df['Year/Ports'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year/Ports'])

print(df)

  Year/Ports  val
0 1952-01-01    1
1 1953-01-01    2
2 1954-01-01    3
```

Comment: Thank you..I will try this ..infact I sliced the Year/ports in the CSV using excel functions so that works ...i will try to do as per your suggestion so all happens in the program

Comment: If it works, please mark as accepted answer.